# How to check if points form a square using Bitset C++

Tags: c++, math

Bitset its the most efficient way to check if points form a Square.

Reading N values of pairs (x,y), how is the best way to use bitset to calculate the number of squares (and the biggest area) that N pairs form?

Input:

```
9
5 3
1 4
1 3
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 4
3 2
4 2
```

Output:

```
3 -> Number of squares formed by the pairs x,y
5 -> biggest area
```

O(N^2) Solution would be the most efficient way to do this?

My code So far: I think is not correct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct c{

    int x,y;

}A,B,coordenadas[3001],R[4];

struct cc{

    long int c1,c2;

}R1,R2;

int quadrados=0,n=0;
long int area;
long int concat[3001];

int bs(long int search)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = n - 1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while( first <= last )
    {
      if ( concat[middle] < search )
         first = middle + 1;
      else if ( concat[middle] == search )
      {
         return 1;
         break;
      }
      else
         last = middle - 1;

      middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    if ( first > last )
      return 0;
}

void calculo()
{
    int x=0,y=0,a=0,b=0,limpa=0;


    if(A.y==B.y)
    {
        x=abs(A.x-B.x);
        area=x*x;
        R1.c1=(B.y + x) * 100000 + (A.x);
        R1.c2=(B.y - x) * 100000 + (A.x);
        //R2.c1=(B.y + x) * 100000 + (B.x);
        //R2.c2=(B.y - x) * 100000 + (B.x);
        if((int)bs(R1.c1)==1 && (int)bs(R1.c2)==1)
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;
    }
    else
    if(A.x==B.x)
    {
        x=abs(B.y-A.y);
        area=x*x;
        R1.c1=(B.y) * 100000 + (A.x + x);
        R1.c2=(B.y) * 100000 + (A.x - x);
        //R2.c1=(A.y) * 100000 + (B.x + x);
        //R2.c2=(A.y) * 100000 + (B.x - x);
        if((int)bs(R1.c1)==1 && (int)bs(R1.c2)==1)
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;

    }
    else
    if(A.y>B.y)
    {
        x=abs(B.x-A.x);
        y=abs(B.y-A.y);
        area=sqrt(x*x+y*y)*sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        R1.c1=(A.y + x) * 100000 + (A.x + y);
        R1.c2=(B.y + x) * 100000 + (B.x + y);
        //R2.c1=(A.y - x) * 100000 + (A.x - y);
        //R2.c2=(B.y - x) * 100000 + (B.x - y);
        if((int)bs(R1.c1)==1 && (int)bs(R1.c2)==1)
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;
    }
    else
    if(A.y<B.y)
    {
        x=abs(B.y-A.y);
        y=abs(B.x-A.x);
        area=sqrt(x*x+y*y)*sqrt(x*x+y*y);
        R1.c1=(B.y + y) * 100000 + (B.x - x);
        R1.c2=(A.y + y) * 100000 + (A.x - x);
        //R2.c1=(B.y - y) * 100000 + (B.x + x);
        //R2.c2=(A.y - y) * 100000 + (A.x + x);
        if((int)bs(R1.c1)==1 && (int)bs(R1.c2)==1)
        quadrados+=1;
        else
        area=0;

    }

//  printf("Area=%ld e R0-> (%d,%d) e R1 (%d,%d) R2 (%d,%d) R3 (%d,%d)\n",area,R[0].x,R[0].y,R[1].x,R[1].y,R[2].x,R[2].y,R[3].x,R[3].y);
}

int main() {

    int M=1,mArea=0;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin >> coordenadas[i].x >> coordenadas[i].y;concat[i]=coordenadas[i].y * 100000 + coordenadas[i].x;}
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        A.x=coordenadas[i].x;A.y=coordenadas[i].y;
        for(int ii=M;ii<n;ii++)
        {
            B.x=coordenadas[ii].x;B.y=coordenadas[ii].x;
            calculo();
            if(mArea<area)
            mArea=area;
        }
        M+=1;
    }

    if(quadrados==0)
    cout << quadrados << endl;
    else
    cout << quadrados << endl << mArea << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you using `std::bitset`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: The solution I have in mind is `n² log(n)`...

Comment: i dont know how to use bitset but I'm sure that its better then the way I'm building my code. I'm just reading 2 pairs at the same time, an then i calculate the 2 points that forms a square. Then I use a binary search to check if the points exist. If yes i cout n_squares++ and i save the area. The problem is that this is a O(N^2 * log(V)), little bit slow.

Comment: Please share your full code here, it will help us to understand what you try to do.

Comment: You have `std::binary_search` (or `std::lower_bound`) instead of your `bs`. You may also use `std::vector` instead of fixed sized arrays.

Comment: I'm building a more or less good solution. Well, im not sure if I'm realy doing the right calculus. I'm guessig 4 positions, horizontal vertical and then the 2 sides. Is it ok or there is a better solution?

Comment: With the correct formulation, you may factorize your 4 cases into one. (and fix the error in formula).

Comment: Can we assume that geometry is discrete (integer values)?